# DotNet Maui BlazorGoogleMaps

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, maui-blazor, blazorgooglemaps

[image]I'm using BlazorGoogleMaps in my DotNet Maui application. I can generate a map with routes but how do I add the live driving functionality to follow the route? Similar to the one on the google maps application?

I have tried using a timer to set the center of the map using geolocation. But this still shows the full map and its not the same as the google maps start feature where it zooms in your location and follows the map

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue? Or a sample code of what you've tried so far. Also see [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services. (d) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features.](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) of their ToS. As it states there that you can't recreate the navigation feature like the google maps app programmatically. What you can do though is [contact sales](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation) If you want to try Navigation SDK.